# How to implement salesforce in my hotel businesses

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

I run multiples hotel in different locations, Bali, Ibiza and Marrakesh, each hotel have a website, how to optimize salesforce in my processes work and what task i need to organize for my team in the offices?The question is can i use sale force in unique account for 3 different hotel locations?

Comment: This is going to be far too broad a topic for this site. Salesforce does support process automation but from the amount of information you have given it is not clear what you are looking for it to do with Salesforce - e..g. lead management, marketing, customer management, room booking?

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, i thinking about have salesforce implement in all automation process you mention.